# SAS libname odbc prompt not prompting

Tags: sas, odbc

I am trying to write a libname statement in SAS Enterprise Guide to refer to an existing ODBC connection to a SQL database. This program is shared with others, so coding my user name and password in it is not an option. Ideally I would like to the program to prompt me for a user name and password, but I can't get it to work. Here is what I have tried:

Works (but is not acceptable): 
`libname libref odbc dsn=DSN_Name uid=User_Name pwd=My_Password;`

(where "libref", "DSN_Name", "User_Name", and "My_Password" are my actual values)

Does not work:

a)  `libname libref odbc dsn=DSN_Name;`

**result:** ERROR: CLI error trying to establish connection: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Login failed for user ''.
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.

b)   `libname libref odbc dsn=DSN_Name prompt=yes;`

**result:** ERROR: CLI error trying to establish connection: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver 
       specified : [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string attribute
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.

c) `libname libref odbc prompt=yes;`

**result:** ERROR: CLI error trying to establish connection: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver 
       specified : [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Invalid connection string attribute
ERROR: Error in the LIBNAME statement.

plus a bunch of other such combos. I feel like I am missing something, but what? Are there other options which don't involve me writing my password in and inevitably forgetting to delete it? Thank you!

Comment: The PROMPT option on the libname statement requires you to be running Display Manager.  If you are using Enterprise Guide (or SAS/Studio) as your user interface to run SAS code then that will not work.  More likely you will want to use the prompt feature of EG to create a macro variable that can be used in the SAS code.

Comment: @Tom, thank you! I hadn't noticed anything saying that the prompt option was _only_ for Display Manager. I did some googling and figured out how to make the Enterprise Guide prompts work for me, although I do wish it were as simple as the prompt option in the libname statement looks to be. I have so many programs to update :(